# How to correctly interpret f-regression values during feature selection

Tags: feature-selection, scikit-learn

I am new to machine learning. I would like to know how correctly interpret scikit-learn's [`f_regression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression.html) values, in order to perform a good feature selection (I'm using [`f_regression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression.html) as score function for [`SelectKBest()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html)).

More precisely: Is a feature with a high value *always* better than one with a lower value? How should I interpret [`f_regression`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_regression.html)'s values when I am using categorical variables?

Answer (score 1):

Pick the variables with the highest F-statistic. If you want, you can use a more handy function, like [`feature_selection.SelectPercentile`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectPercentile.html).

```
selector = feature_selection.SelectPercentile(feature_selection.f_regression, percentile=30)
selector.fit(X_train, y_train)
selector.get_support(True)
```

The method [`get_support`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectPercentile.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectPercentile.get_support) (with `True`) will return the indexes of the selected features, according to the percentile.

Comment: Feature selection causes enormous problems.  See for example https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/